# Mute browser from a C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

Is it possible to mute Flash and/or Firefox from a .Net app? Our app knows when it's about to initiate a phone call, so it would nice if it could mute any streamed audio on the user's browser.

Let's assume the user is known to use Firefox and the streamed content will be Flash based.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393438/abuse-of-adobe-flash) mentions some tools to mute Flash and FlashMute looks good but how to create a similar utility or else automate an existing tool like FlashMute?

Comment: Do you need to support Windows XP?

Comment: What sort of application needs to do the muting? Is it a web application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get hold of application mixer and control volume of individual applications: [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer)