# Mute SoundPlayer for just my app

Tags: c#, audio

I wish to mute the sound for only my WPF application and leave the overall mixer as the user had it set.

I can mute/unmute the system wide sound using the following code.

But I notice when my app is running and a sound is playing, my app appears in the windows mixer and I can mute/unmute just my app via the mixer's UI so it seems like it should be possible for my app to do it programmatically.

```
private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle, (IntPtr) APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controling Volume Mixer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in Vista/7/8 where there is per application volume control

```
DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);

[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);

/// <summary>
/// Returns volume from 0 to 10
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Volume from 0 to 10</returns>
public static int GetVolume()
{
  uint CurrVol = 0;
  waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out CurrVol);
  ushort CalcVol = (ushort)(CurrVol & 0x0000ffff);
  int volume = CalcVol / (ushort.MaxValue / 10);
  return volume;
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets volume from 0 to 10
/// </summary>
/// <param name="volume">Volume from 0 to 10</param>
public static void SetVolume(int volume)
{
  int NewVolume = ((ushort.MaxValue / 10) * volume);
  uint NewVolumeAllChannels = (((uint)NewVolume & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint)NewVolume << 16));
  waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, NewVolumeAllChannels);
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a correct way to set volume for the application, but not to mute it. Muting it in the windows mixer will remember the previous value for "unmute", setting it to 0 will not.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the calls to play sounds, you can have these functions check some resource to indicate if the user has chosen to mute the sound or not, e.g. :

```
public void PlaySoundXYZ() 
{
   if(!MuteSource.IsMuted()) 
   {
        // play sound.
   }
}
```