# How to use Core Audio API Master Volume Control with a friendly name?

Tags: c#, volume

I am using this code provided here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control

I am trying to control the volume of my application and 1 additional process that my application starts.  Is there a way to use this code above as per application instead of master?

Here is the code in the form

```
            MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            device = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
            beiVolumControl.EditValue = (int)(device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar * 100);
```

By comments listed there is a way to pick the device using a friendly name but I don't see any examples listed anywhere.

Here is the code used when my volume slider changes

```
        //change the Volume
    void ritbVolumeControl_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TrackBarControl trackBar = sender as TrackBarControl;
        //only use in vista or above.
        if (useAlternateSound == false)
        {
            device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = ((float)trackBar.Value / 100.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            //probably using xp or lower.
        }
        // MessageBox.Show(trackBar.Value.ToString());


    }
```

The End Goal is to Control my Application and one other process's volume if it's possible without controlling the master volume of all applications.  So I can mute them and still use skype voice chat for an example. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: A similar question and solution to is described in this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer