# Trouble with IAudioSessionControl2, to mute WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, browser, core-audio, mute

The goal was to mute a WebBrowser control that could have Flash video playing. So I found this code which is quite useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322736/990618

Problem is some of the enumerations are nulls when you'd expect some kind of id from `GetDisplayName`, I'd get 3-4 blanks and 2 that are ok like "Mozilla Firefox" and `"@%SystemRoot%\System32\AudioSrv.Dll,-202"` which is system sounds.

So went ahead and tried GetProcessId, GetSessionIdentifier and GetSessionInstanceIdentifier.

`GetProcessId` would return only zeros and ones, `GetSessionIdentifier` same result as `GetDisplayName`, `GetSessionInstanceIdentifier` all blanks.

Why these blanks and zeros and ones?

Here's the modified `EnumerateApplications`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateApplications()
{
  // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
  IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
  IMMDevice speakers;
  deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

  // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
  Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
  object o;
  speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
  IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

  // enumerate sessions for on this device
  IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
  mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
  int count;
  sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    IAudioSessionControl ctl;
    IAudioSessionControl2 ctl2;

    sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);

    ctl2 = ctl as IAudioSessionControl2;

    string dn;

    UInt32 pid = 0;

    string sout = "";

    if (ctl2 != null)
      ctl2.GetSessionIdentifier(out sout);

    //ctl.GetDisplayName(out dn);
    //  ctl2.GetProcessId(out pid);

    //yield return pid.ToString();
    yield return sout;

    if (ctl != null)
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);

    if (ctl2 != null)
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl2);
  }

  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
}


[Guid("bfb7ff88-7239-4fc9-8fa2-07c950be9c6d"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IAudioSessionControl2
{
  [PreserveSig]
  int GetProcessId([Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out UInt32 processId);

  [PreserveSig]
  int GetSessionIdentifier([Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

  [PreserveSig]
  int GetSessionInstanceIdentifier([Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the correct declaration for the `CoreAudio` interfaces makes all the difference...

I used your code, but used the interfaces declaration from the [CoreAudioNET](http://whenimbored.xfx.net/2011/01/core-audio-for-net/) library and everything works as expected:
[image: output]

Since the code is quite extensive I will not paste it here, instead, you can download it from this link: [Source Code](http://software.xfx.net/stackoverflow/Colin_CoreAudio.zip)

Comment: Thank you so so much! Works perfect! Used GetProcessId with GetWindowThreadProcessId all's working, finally! Much appreciated!