# How to change volumes of individual programs?

Tags: c#, .net, volume, mixer

I want to be able to change the volume of a single program just like I do with the Mixer that is embedded to Vista and Win7(I don't know about Win8). I couldn't find any sample code or reference that will get me going. I prefer to use .NET platform but C and C++ is also OK...

Comment: It's already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this example in Codeproject. it's a sample documentation of

[Windows Audio Mixer API Wrapper Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30296/Windows-Audio-Mixer-API-Wrapper-Library)

Hope will help it.