# How to control voice balance via C# code

Tags: c#

I am developing an application in C#, at some point of the program, I'd like to have control of the speaker, more specifically, I'd like to control the voice balance (which speaker - left/right - the voice is coming from). Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controling Volume Mixer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer)

Comment: How are you doing the audio?

Comment: I have two speakers setup. It's a very basic audio play. If I understand you correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using the audio. If you have a two speaker setup, then all you need to do is to create a sound that only plays on the left or right chanel - depending on your requirements.

I have not done this recently, but a few opensource libraries you could have a look at are:

- http://windowsmedianet.sourceforge.net/
- http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Also check out the multimedia MSDN entry:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712636(VS.85).aspx

Hope this helps.

Cheers.