# Mute external Application [WinXP - Win8]

Tags: c#, windows, audio, mute

Is there a way to mute/unmute external Application's sound?

It has to be compatible from WinXP to Win8.
I'm writing an API DLL, so an external exe(like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)) is not possible.

I appreciate any help/links to references

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Already tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer), it's working but since it's only for >Win7, I need another solution. And there isn't that much to find, the most Sites only cover systemwide Volume Control