# Retrieve the current system volume, NOT level

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to point out immediately that I do not want the level, every answer I've seen so far has to do with people wanting the level so they can make meters. I need to find out how to get the system volume.

The closest I have come is using this pinvoke

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);
```

But that only gets the audio of my application, I need the "master" system volume.

Comment: If you aren't expecting volume *level*, then what *are* you expecting?

Comment: @rory.ap he wants the value of the volume slider as opposed to how many decibels an audio channel reports (so they can do visualizations or meters)

Comment: @rory.ap Volume and Level are not the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the ISimpleAudioVolume interface? That lets you get the master volume.

Comment: It looks like what I want, but saw no usage example on MSDN so am lost as to implementation.

Comment: @Wobbles, looks pretty hairy, but here is some code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer

Comment: That pertains to application volume, but I actually found some code that showed its use for master volume buried in a forum. Now my next step is to find out if there is a window message or some other event I can attach to to know when it changes so I don't have to pool it.