# How to get Speaker Volume Level?

Tags: c#, speaker

How can I get the speaker volume in C#?

[speaker volume image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnYkG.png)

And show it in my app?

[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzuKc.png)

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: There's lots of answers on stack already for working with Windows volume using user32.dll.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please note that the [tagging guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) recommend against putting tags (e.g. C#) in your question title; the tagging system is more than adequate.

Comment: I do not have the code

Comment: jeroenh I want to get speaker volume device no a program

Comment: @آرمان غروی [this answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322736/20047) should get you started. Ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio), you could do the following:

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
.....
//  download NAudio.dll from https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/releases
//  and add it as Reference to the project

var devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var defaultDevice = devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
var volume = defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume;
float leftVolumePercent = volume.Channels[0].VolumeLevelScalar * 100;
float rightVolumePercent = volume.Channels[1].VolumeLevelScalar * 100;
float masterVolumePercent = volume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar * 100;
```

This [article](https://eskerahn.dk/wordpress/?p=2089) demonstrates, how to achieve such things without external frameworks.