# Change balance level for audio volume from powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, audio, volume

While I have read several solutions to changing the volume using Powershell:

[How can I mute/unmute my sound from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255419/how-can-i-mute-unmute-my-sound-from-powershell/19348221#19348221)

[Change audio level from powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355891/change-audio-level-from-powershell)

I couldnt find anything that changes the balance. Something like:

```
#Sets left channel volume to 20%
Set-Speaker -LeftChannel 20

#Sets right channel volume to 80%
Set-Speaker -RightChannel 80
```

Just to be clear, Im talking about modifying this:

[image]

I need it to set a startup script that maintains my current (or last) volume but keeps the left channel always at 20%

Thanks

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592751/7571258

Comment: That is for C#; I would need it for Powershell.

Comment: You can use inline C# code in PowerShell, using `Add-Type -TypeDefinition`.

Comment: Please post a example

Comment: I was able to make it

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348221/162407

Answer (score 2):

To take zett42's functional collection of ideas and a small mistake at the end and actually put it together into an answer:

1. Get the code from the [AudioManager.cs](https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386) gist and put it in a file `AudioManager.cs` where the script will be
2. In that `AudioManager.cs` file, make `GetMasterVolumeObject()` `public` so it is more convenient to use from a helper class, by replacing the line:

```
private static IAudioEndpointVolume GetMasterVolumeObject()
```

with

```
public static IAudioEndpointVolume GetMasterVolumeObject()
```

3. Now in your PowerShell script you can do:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $(
    $(Get-Content -Path "AudioManager.cs" -Raw) + 
    @'
        public static class AudioSettings { 
                public static void SetChannelVolumeLevel(uint channelNumber, float newLevel)
                {
                    VideoPlayerController.IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
                    try
                    {
                        masterVol = VideoPlayerController.AudioManager.GetMasterVolumeObject();
                        if (masterVol == null)
                            return;

                        masterVol.SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(channelNumber, newLevel/100, Guid.Empty);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (masterVol != null)
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
                    }
                }               
                
        }       
'@)

[AudioSettings]::SetChannelVolumeLevel(0, 60)
[AudioSettings]::SetChannelVolumeLevel(1, 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592751/7571258), you need to call `SetChannelVolumeLevel` or `SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar` method of `IAudioEndpointVolume`. The interop method is included in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386), but it is missing a convenient wrapper method.

For getting started, you need to include the C# code in PowerShell using `Add-Type`:

```sh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
-paste C# code here-
'@
```

Add this method to class `AudioManager`:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the channel volume to a specific level
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channelNumber">Channel number, which can be 0..(numberOfChannels-1)</param>
        /// <param name="newLevel">Value between 0 and 100 indicating the desired scalar value of the volume</param>
        public static void SetChannelVolumeLevel(uint channelNumber, float newLevel)
        {
            IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
            try
            {
                masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
                if (masterVol == null)
                    return;

                masterVol.SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(channelNumber, newLevel/100, Guid.Empty);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (masterVol != null)
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
            }
        }
```

I've inserted it before line `private static IAudioEndpointVolume GetMasterVolumeObject()`, but it doesn't really matter where you put it within the class.

Now you can call it from PowerShell like this:

```sh
[VideoPlayerController.AudioManager]::SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(0, 60)
[VideoPlayerController.AudioManager]::SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(1, 40)
```

On my system it moves both left and right volume equally but I propably suffer from locked balance. There is a registry tweak [described here](https://www.guidingtech.com/adjust-audio-balance-windows-10/) which didn't work for me though.