# alter windows stereo mixer sound output with windows api c++

Tags: c++, windows

With these windows API headers I can play sound, but I want to edit/alter sound equalization of stereo mixer output with c++.

Currently:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

  WINMMAPI MMRESULT WINAPI mixerOpen(LPHMIXER phmx,UINT uMxId,DWORD_PTR dwCallback,DWORD_PTR dwInstance,DWORD fdwOpen);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/audio-mixer-functions

Comment: You can look into equalizer project. I use it for personal use: [https://github.com/chebum/equalizer-apo-64](https://github.com/chebum/equalizer-apo-64)

Comment: it looks like it has a dependency --You will need standard Equalizer APO installed on your system.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controlling-volume-mixer). Same APIs, but you'll need to translate the code from C#. [The MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is also a good place to start.

Comment: do you know how to call this in c++ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-mixersetcontroldetails   , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/audio-mixer-functions