# Controlling the Volume Mixer

Tags: c#, .net

I've been searching for a long time now for a way to check if a specific application is muted, and if it is, to un-mute it.  This is for an application originally built for Windows XP, but when I run it on Windows 7/10/11 - it keep muting itself every so often during runtime.

I found @Simon Mourier's [Fantastic suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controlling-volume-mixer) but, when I try to test it in Visual Studio 2017 [C# - Console app(.NET Core)] I'm getting an error on the 2 instances of

```
Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
```

The error I'm getting is

> Error CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GUID' and no accessible extension method 'GUID' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, my question is - what am I doing wrong here?

I've found over a dozen different instances of this code being suggested via Google searches, and never a whisper of an error like mine.

Comment: Which .net version are you using? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.guid?view=net-7.0#applies-to seems like all of them have `GUID` for `Type` specified

Comment: make sure to add `using system` on the top of your file

Comment: @RandRandom I have .NET Core 1.1 set as the Target Framework currently

Comment: @zoldxk using System; is the first line

Comment: You need to target at least .NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the quick responses!  @HansPassant's response held the answer for me, I targeted .NET Core 2.1 and it works fine now.

Comment: is there a reason why you are using such an old version? in case you don’t know that version is EOL (End of Life) since August 2021 - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: Noted.  The systems this will be used on are a closed ecosystem with no internet or usb access, so I suppose I could have used a newer version, but I didn't want to add anything else new to the image, so updating to .net 6 or 7 was out.