# NAudio Volume Mixer

Tags: c#, naudio, mixer

IS there a way to control individual volume level using NAudio

Sound Mixer:

[image: Sound Mixer]

I wish reduce most apps like Steam, YouTube to 50%, then restore them
while keeping my app at 100%

I can reduce the total Volume up and down

I have tried

[Controlling Volume Mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controlling-volume-mixer)

Comment: AudioClient.ActivateAsync() takes an optional AudioClientProperties argument.  Which lets you specify the eCategory member, pick AudioStreamCategory.Communications and the OS treats your output as coming from a chat or voip app.  Which automatically ducks the output of all other apps.